# "Setup Pay" text appearing as IN_APP_PAYMENT_BUTTON_SETUP Pay

Tags: objective-c, ios10, applepay

I have localization in my project, when i add the apple pay button it displays `IN_APP_PAYMENT_BUTTON_SETUP` instead of "Setup Pay".

Strangely same code displays proper Apple pay button when added to a different sample project.

```
if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments]) {



        if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:@[PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex]]) {

            //Standard code
        }
        else{

            UIButton *btnApplePay = [PKPaymentButton buttonWithType:PKPaymentButtonTypeSetUp style:PKPaymentButtonStyleWhiteOutline];
            [btnApplePay setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 294, 50)];
            [self.view addSubview:btnApplePay];


        }
    }
```

Also if the width of the PKPaymentButton is of size smaller than 128 px then the PKPaymentButton displays " Pay" text.

Comment: If you are creating the payment button in your storyboard then you don't call `initWithPaymentButtonType`. If you want to create the button programmatically then you don't add it in the storyboard and you must nsure that you add the button to your view hierarchy.

Comment: Even if i use `buttonWithType` instead of `initWithPaymentButtonType` , when i have the button from storyboard the same problem persists and same is the case if i create a button in code instead of using a button from storyboard file.

Comment: If you are creating the button from the storyboard then you don't need any code; you must set the button type in the storyboard. If you are creating with code, make sure you are adding the button; show that code

Comment: Then how will i give the type and style in storyboard if not code. If i create from code then this is the way i do it  `UIButton *btnPay = [PKPaymentButton buttonWithType:PKPaymentButtonTypeSetup style:PKPaymentButtonStyleWhiteOutline];
[self.view addSubview:btnPay];`

Comment: I don't think that you can even create a pkpaymentbutton from the storyboard. If you creating it from code you will need to set the frame or add constraints

Comment: We can change the default class from `UIButton` to `PKPaymentButton` in Storyboard. But even if i ignore it and try to add the button from code, its not working. Would appreciate if you could share a working code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149287/discussion-between-aditya-and-paulw11).

Comment: @Paulw11Update, it turns out that it has got nothing to do with adding the button in storyboard or code, apparently the width of the button was the actual issue. Now i am facing a different sort of issue. I have localization in my project, when i add the apple pay button it displays `IN_APP_PAYMENT_BUTTON_SETUP`. Strangely same code display proper Apple pay button when added to a different sample project.

Comment: I've few questions Aditya.
Does it appear like this for all the languages supported[English]? Are you trying to change language within app or from default system settings? & have you tried with Adding localization in your sample project i.e. same scenario?

Comment: Hi Ellen, yes it appears for other language that i am supporting viz arabic. Yes i have the functionality of changing the language from the app itself. Yes i did try adding localization in the sample app too, after adding localization in the sample app this is not reproduced.

Comment: Ok.if you try with changing language from device settings, does it work .. if you are changing within app then it is having issue?

Comment: Actually even if i load the app with default language which is English this problem happens. Secondly the above mentioned text is visible if button if of larger size. For normal size like 128 px it just displays Pay

Comment: One point i would like to bring to notice is i am using BundleLocalization https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization to change language inside the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINALLY, I found the reason behind this whole issue.

As I have mentioned in my comments, I was able to find the root cause of this issue, which was Localization.

I tried to replicate the same code and environment in a demo app but was not able to reproduce the same behavior. Finally i was able to pin point the exact cause viz `BundleLocalization` which I have used in my app, as I need to change languages inside the app on the fly.

As I dug deep inside the `BundleLocalization` class, I was able to figure out that there is a category use called `NSBundle+Localization`which has a method called:

`-(NSString*) customLocaLizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName`

Apparently, this messes up the `localizationBundle`. So, I have to find a workaround for this, in order to continue using localization in my app.